# It is normal for an OAuth2 implementation to create a new access token every authentication?

Tags: django, oauth

I'm using an OAuth 2.0 implementation (django-ouath-toolkit) and I noticed that every time an user request a access token I get a new registry in my database. This is a normal behaviour? They should not be recycled/replaced by application and user every authentication request?
If an user logs in 5 times in a row, all the 5 returned access tokens will be stored and will be valid until it expires.
If it is relevant, I'm using `password` grant type and public client type.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the common practice: New Access-Token is created on each authentication request.

It is, however, somewhat uncommon that user would log in 5 times in a row.

Comment: There is any "flow" for auth proccess with oauth 2.0? How can I check if the access token is yet valid?